# How to write HOC for React Apollo Query component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to write HOC for displaying info of used Query in component like this:

```
const GET_RATES = gql`
  query ratesQuery {
    rates(currency: "USD") {
      currency
      rate
    }
  }
`;

class RatesQuery extends Query<{
  rates: { currency: string; rate: string }[];
}> {}

const RatesQueryWithInfo = withQueryInfo(RatesQuery);

const Rates = () => (
  <RatesQueryWithInfo query={GET_RATES}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error || !data) return "Error!";

      return (
        <div>
          {data.rates.map(rate => (
            <div key={rate.currency}>
              {rate.currency}: {rate.rate}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </RatesQueryWithInfo>
);
```

`withQueryInfo` looks like (implementation of it is based on [article](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb)):

```
const withVerbose = <P extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) =>
  class extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {(this.props as any).query.loc.source.body}
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props as P} />;
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

This HOC works fine (it is appending query string in above original component) but the typings are broken

Error in `withQueryInfo(RatesQuery)`

```
Argument of type 'typeof RatesQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<QueryProps<{ rates: { currency: string; rate: string; }[]; }, OperationVariables>>'.
  Type 'typeof RatesQuery' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<QueryProps<{ rates: { currency: string; rate: string; }[]; }, OperationVariables>, any>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type '{ client: Requireable<object>; children: Validator<(...args: any[]) => any>; fetchPolicy: Requireable<string>; notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: Requireable<boolean>; onCompleted: Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>; ... 5 more ...; partialRefetch: Requireable<...>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<QueryProps<{ rates: { currency: string; rate: string; }[]; }, OperationVariables>>'.
        Types of property 'fetchPolicy' are incompatible.
          Type 'Requireable<string>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<"cache-first" | "cache-and-network" | "network-only" | "cache-only" | "no-cache" | "standby" | null | undefined>'.
            Types of property '[nominalTypeHack]' are incompatible.
              Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '"cache-first" | "cache-and-network" | "network-only" | "cache-only" | "no-cache" | "standby" | null | undefined'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"cache-first" | "cache-and-network" | "network-only" | "cache-only" | "no-cache" | "standby" | null | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

And also `{ loading, error, data }` implicitly has an 'any' type.

CodeSanbox for this example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hamilton-5mb5l?fontsize=14&initialpath=%2Fsrc&module=%2Fsrc%2FRates.tsx).

**How to write proper types for this HOC?**

Comment: I'm not sure about the initial error but you can give the query result a QueryResult type by a.) Importing {QueryResult} from react-apollo. B.) Declaring the type as follows: ({loading, data, error}:QueryResult)

Comment: @MichaelKnight yes it's only a partial solution, but `data` is not typed when `QueryResult` is used. My goal is to do not touch the original `RatesQueryWithInfo` when wrapped in HOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read this is there is a mismatch between the declared `propTypes` in the `Query` component and `QueryProps` (the props for that component). The props that are wrong are are fixed below (with the original type in the comments):

```
export default class Query<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables> extends React.Component<QueryProps<TData, TVariables>> {
    static propTypes: {
        // ...
        client: PropTypes.Requireable<ApolloClient<any>>; //PropTypes.Requireable<object>;
        // ...
        fetchPolicy: PropTypes.Requireable<FetchPolicy>; //PropTypes.Requireable<string>;
        // ...
        query: PropTypes.Validator<DocumentNode>; // PropTypes.Validator<object>;
    };
}
```

This incompatibility does not usually matter much, except for when you try to create a HOC and use `React.ComponentType<P>` which validates that the `propTypes` and props are in agreement.

The simplest solution (baring a PR to react-apollo) is to use a weaker type for `WrappedComponent`, one which does not validate `propTypes`.

With the definition below the client code works as expected:

```
interface WeakComponentClass<P = {}, S = React.ComponentState> extends React.StaticLifecycle<P, S> {
  new (props: P, context?: any): React.Component<P, S>;
}

const withVerbose = <P extends any>(
  WrappedComponent: WeakComponentClass<P> | React.FunctionComponent<P>
) =>
  class extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {(this.props as any).query.loc.source.body}
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props as P} />;
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

**NOTE:** I hesitate to submit a PR with the corrected types as although they fix the typing issue, they do no accurately reflect the run-time validations done by `propTypes`. Perhaps a better approach would be to change the behavior of `Validator<T>` in react itself to not be co-variant, but to be contra-variant instead.

Using this definition of  `Validator`, react-apollo works as expected:

```
export interface Validator<T> {
    (props: object, propName: string, componentName: string, location: string, propFullName: string): Error | null;
    [nominalTypeHack]?: (p: T) => void; // originally T, now behaves contra-variantly 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. Can you explain what is `WeakComponentClass`? Or the best will be if you provide modified CodeSanbox based on my example with this `WeakComponentClass`.

Comment: @Everettss wops .. it was late last night and I forgot to post that interface. It's just a custom interafce for a class component that only contains the constructor and does not do any checks on anything else. Added it to the answer